# Greediness in VBA RegEx

Tags: excel, regex, vba

My string is the following

```
[[FOOTNOTE 23]] + [[FOOTNOTE 1787] +  182 - x +[[XYZ123]] + [[CD78G]]
```

My goal is to catch all keywords that start and end with double brackets.  Note that `[[FOOTNOTE 1787]` ends with just a single bracket so it should not match

My RegEx pattern looks like this:

```
\[\[\w{5,}.*?\]\]?
```

This seems to work except that it also matches `[[FOOTNOTE 123]` which it should not.

I realize that the `?` at the end means that char is optional.

What I am trying to do is

1. make the last character required (double bracket),
2. but make the *entire* pattern match in a non-greedy fashion.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You were close. What you need is `[^[\]]*` (0 or more characters that are not square brackets):

```
\[\[\w{5,}[^[\]]*\]\]
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HWZApZ/1).

This regex matches:

```
[[FOOTNOTE 23]] + [[FOOTNOTE 1787] +  182 - x +[[XYZ123]] + [[CD78G]]
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  that does seem to do the trick.  I will have to try to understand this a little better, but that does seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

> *"... My goal is to catch all keywords that start and end with double brackets.  Note that `[[FOOTNOTE 1787]` ends with just a single bracket so it should not match ..."*

You can assert that the keyword within the brackets is not a `]`.

```
\[\[[^]]+?]]
```

This will match,

- *[[FOOTNOTE 23]]*
- *[[XYZ123]]*
- and *[[CD78G]]*

Comment: Solution confirmed by [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QzlkBV/1).

Answer (score 1):

If there can be a single closing square bracket present between the double closing ones:

```
\[\[\w{5}(?:(?!\]\]|\[\[).)*\]\]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[\[` Match `[[`
- `\w{5}` Match 5 word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `(?!\]\]|\[\[).` Assert that from the current position there is not `[[` or `]]` directly to the right, and if that is true match a single character using the dot
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `\]\]` Match `]]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q6qh1k/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
\[\[[\w\s]+?]]
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5J1nIJ/1)